# Is it possible to show the like button on my page without the "You and [n] others like this"

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-developers

As this question is not about the facebook app development, but just how to properly customize the like button I hope this question is in good hands at this place.

The button can be customized using the [Facebook Like Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/) customizer. There is a way to hide faces and to hide the share button.

But (how) can I disable that "You, Another Name and 7 others like this." crap?